# The mean shifted outlier model

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, least-squares, mean-shift

In the OLS setting, the mean shifted outlier model connects two behaviors:

1. delete the $i^{th}$ observation
2. adding a variable

In other words, assume the original model, $\omega$ ,is:

$$ Y = X\beta + \epsilon$$

with $\epsilon$ ~ $N_n(0,{\sigma}^2 I$). Next, we add a variable to the model above with all other assumptions remaining the same:

$$ Y = X\beta + \theta u_i+ \epsilon$$

where $\theta$ is the parameter associated with $u_i$. We denote this model as $\Omega$.

Now the claim is if $u_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column from the identity matrix, the modified model above is the same as deleting the $i^{th}$ observation of the original OLS model.

Can anyone prove the following:

$$\hat{\beta_{\Omega}} = \hat{\beta_{\omega}} - \frac{e_i}{1 - h_{ii}}   (X^TX)^{-1} {x_i}^T $$

where $e_i$ is the $i^{th}$ element of the residual $e$ of the original model, ${x_i}^T$is the $i^{th}$ row of the matrix $X$, and $h_{ii}$ is the $i^{th}$element of the diagonal of the hat matrix $H$.

Comment: Any answers or even thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this looks like routine bookwork (and so would likely fall under the `self-study` tag [q.v.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)). Is this for a class? Your own study?

Comment: @Glen_b This is for a class at stanford. I just figured out. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a rough outline of your approach below so that your question has an answer?

Comment: @Glen_b check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to understand that (1) and (2) accomplish the same thing is to recognize that adding a column with a single $1$ at row $i$ (which is (2)) enables you to column-reduce the model matrix $X$, zeroing out all its entries in row $i$ (which is (1)). Thus the two approaches are really the same model for the leave-one-out dataset. Since the reparameterization accomplished by the column reduction does not affect the original variables, the coefficients associated with the original variables must be the same.

---

The calculations are easily done using block matrix notation.  To keep focused on the concepts, let's suppose that any matrices we wish to invert are, in fact, invertible.  Then

$$\hat \beta = (X^\prime X)^{-1} X^\prime y$$

is the original estimate.  Without any loss of generality (we may always permute the rows of $X$ and $y$ in parallel), assume $i=n$, so that we're contemplating deleting the last observation.  Bordering $X$ on the right by $u_i = u_n$ gives the $n\times (p+1)$ block matrix

$$X_0 = \pmatrix{X & u_n} = \pmatrix{X_{(n)} & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \pmatrix{\mathbb{I}_{p} & 0 \\ x_n & 1} = \pmatrix{X_{(n)} & 0 \\ 0 & 1} W.$$

I have written $X_{(n)}$ for $X$ with its last row removed, $x_n$ for the last row, and $\mathbb{I}_{p}$ for the $p$ identity matrix.  (Later on, I will also write $y_{(n)}$ for the response with component $n$ removed.)  $W$ is, in effect, a record of the column operations needed to put $X_0$ into the block-diagonal form seen at the right.  Its inverse is obtained by negating the $x_n$ terms in the bottom left.

The new estimates based on $X_0$ are

$$\pmatrix{\hat\beta_0 \\ \hat\theta} = (X_0^\prime X_0)^{-1} X_0^\prime y.$$

Substituting $\pmatrix{X_{(n)} & 0 \\ 0 & 1} W$ for $X_0$ throughout gives

$$\pmatrix{\hat\beta_0 \\ \hat\theta} = \pmatrix{(X_{(n)}^\prime X_{(n)})^{-1}X_{(n)}^\prime & 0 \\ -x_n (X_{(n)}^\prime X_{(n)})^{-1}X_{(n)}^\prime & 1} y.$$

By comparing the first $p$ coefficients it is immediate that

$$\hat \beta_0 = (X_{(n)}^\prime X_{(n)})^{-1}X_{(n)}^\prime y_{(n)} = \hat \beta_{(n)},$$

the estimate obtained upon removing the last observation, *QED*.

Incidentally, since $x_n (X_{(n)}^\prime X_{(n)})^{-1}X_{(n)}^\prime y_{(n)} = x_n \hat \beta_{(n)} = \hat y_n$ is the prediction for $x_n$ based on all the other data,

$$\hat \theta = y_n - x_n\hat\beta_{(n)} = y_n - \hat y_n = e_n,$$

the residual.  This is intuitively clear: the new variable gives us the flexibility to achieve a perfect fit of $y_n$, which is achieved by subtracting its residual.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, we have to consider a more general case, i.e, $u_i$ is just a random vector instead of being a column of the identity matrix. Take the expected value of both sides of the equation, we have

$$E(Y) = X\beta + \theta v_i $$

So if we have the design matrix $X$ and response variable $y$ beforehand, we can write

$$y = X \hat{\beta} + \hat{\theta} v_i$$

where $\theta$ is the parameter associated with $v_i$.

Multiply both sides of the equation above by $X^T$ and ${v_i}^T$, we will have

$$X^T y = X^TX\hat{\beta} + X^T \hat{\theta} v_i$$

$${v_i}^T y = {v_i}^TX\hat{\beta} + {v_i}^T\hat{\theta} v_i$$

Solve the equations for $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\theta}$, we will have

$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{{v_i}^T Py}{{v_i}^TPv_i}$$

where P = I - H and

$$\hat{\beta_{\Omega}} = \hat{\beta_{\omega}} - (X^TX)^{-1}X^Tv_i\hat{\theta}$$

Replace $v_i$ with $u_i$, the $i^{th}$ column of the identity matrix, one will get the equation in the question.

Now, why bother doing this? We already have frameworks to deal with add-variable situation and delete-observation situation. But if one investigates in both situations individually, the derivation of the equations above will be much more complicated(including inverse a block matrix). The method explained above is rather simple to understand and it is nice to consider both situations in one model.

Comment: Thanks. One query though ... did you mean to have $v_i$ on both sides of this: $v_i = \frac{{v_i}^T Py}{{v_i}^TPv_i}$?? Should the LHS be $\hat{\theta}$ say? Should the $\theta$ in the next equation have a hat?